# Filtering numeral entries on a range by user form with VBA

Tags: excel, filter, userform, vba

I have a user form for filtering my desired inputs in all available tables in each sheet. It works perfect for text strings, I can select a big range of data for multiple filtering and so on. But I can't do any filtering on the numeral fields! It just returns nothing! I am wondering what I am doing wrong! Thanks for your support.

Here is the form image and the code i have for filter:

[image: My User Form for Free Filtering]

```
Public Sub Filter()
On Error Resume Next
Call Ref.appl_start
Dim sel As Range
    Dim e() As Variant
nn = Application.Match(fltr.ComboBox2.Value, header, 0)
If fltr.CheckBox1 = False And ActiveSheet.FilterMode = True Then Call loreset
Select Case fltr.TextBox3.Value
Case "Selection"
    ReDim e(Selection.Count - 1)
    If Selection.Columns.Count = 1 Then
        e = Application.Transpose(Selection)
    Else
        i = 1
        M = 0
        For Each Rng In Selection.Cells
            If Not Rng.Rows.Hidden And Rng.Value <> "" Then
                e(M) = Selection(i).Value
                M = M + 1
            Else
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Next
    End If
    fr.AutoFilter nn, e, xlFilterValues
Case "Range"
    fr.AutoFilter nn, dict.Keys, xlFilterValues
Case "Clipboard"
Case "Input"
    If IsNumeric(fltr.TextBox2.Value) Or fltr.OptionButton2.Value Then
        fr.AutoFilter nn, fltr.TextBox2.Value
    Else
        fr.AutoFilter nn, "*" & fltr.TextBox2.Value & "*"
    End If
End Select
Call Ref.appl_End
End Sub
```

Comment: What input Case are you using? That gives an error

Comment: this is actually an Add-in I am developing for my own use. my problem is with the multiple numeral fields which for instance I already selected them among some cells and I want to filter my table based on them. In this case if the data type of the field to be filtered was numeral it shows nothing, but if the filed was string, it filter according all of those criteria!

Comment: If you convert the number to String with `CStr`, does it filter? Or You could add a `If IsNumeric()` and just convert numbers to Str. I don't know the data type that your Array have and what you are looking up. But could be type mismatch

Comment: This is a free filter, I wanted to use that freely for different data types. Maybe that is not a good idea at all...